# angularjs nodered signup response not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, database, node-red

I am building a login/register page with html/css/angularJS, Node-red and CloudantNoSQL. I have an example of my code here: 
[https://plnkr.co/edit/tg25kr?p=info](http://plnkr.co/edit/tg25kr?p=info)

```
<!-- Real user service that uses an api -->
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/cornflourblue/angular-registration-login-example/master/app-services/user.service.js"></script>
```

I use the link to the real API code and not local storage as it is in the example.
I am able to display the error message through a response statusCode (303) when the email you fill in isn’t valid. When the email is valid I am able to store the user in the database, but not the success message and action to work. There I have tried statusCode 200, 201 and 202, but none seem to work. 
[Figure 1 http://plnkr.co/edit/tg25kr?p=info](http://plnkr.co/edit/tg25kr?p=info)

Anyone have an idea if there is something wrong with the AngularJS or if my response is incorrect?